# Jump to new line on grouped html code block in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Please I have some problem. How to Jump to New Line after a grouped HTML block code.

Line 6: div class= "content"

Line 7:

Went I type "enter" to Jump to line 7 it doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome! Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's related to extension, try <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).